# Supersized jquery slide show reloads page on iOS devices on zoom in/out

Tags: jquery, supersized

I am using Supersized jquery slide show plugin: http://buildinternet.com/project/supersized/
When viewing the page on Safari it just reloads if you zoom in and zoom out.

Any ideas for the fix?